# Ошибка IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, discord.py

Пытался написать магазин для Discord-бота на Python и столкнулся с ошибкой

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

В БД уже есть несколько товаров.

Вот код:

```py
client = commands.Bot( command_prefix = '%')
connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor() 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shop (
      who TEXT,
      id INT,
      cost BIGINT
  ) """)

@client.command(aliases = ['shop'])
async def __shop(ctx):
  embed = discord.Embed(title='Shop', colour = discord.Color.green())
  embed.set_footer(text = 'Request by {}'.format(ctx.author.name), icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url)
  for row in cursor.execute("SELECT id, cost FROM shop"):
    embed.add_field(
      name = f'Стоимость **{row[1]} :dollar:**',
      value = f'Вы приобретете {cursor.execute("SELECT who FROM shop")}',
      inline = False
      )
  await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

Вот текст ошибки:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключена в том, что вы выходите за пределы кортежа (tuple). Попробуйте вписать в цикл -1, чтобы он не выходил за пределы ( так как `spisok1=(1,20,3)` - для питона, чтобы получить `20` нужно написать `print (spisok1[1])` )

Если остались вопросы - дайте знать